# how to connect aspnetdb database user table with login control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a problem regarding asp.net. I created a user, role, membership and other related tables using aspnet_regsql or aspnet administration and management wizard. in this way
a database aspnetdb.mdf is created in asp_data folder. in this database user table stores all the information about user credentials. now my question is that how can i connect this users table to login control provided in the toolbox. is it possible to connect these aspnetdb database tables with login control or i will have to create a separate login interface for it.

Comment: Is SQL server running? Can you BEFORE you try any logon stuff also create a simple table called "test' in that database, and can you create a simple web page without a logon that pulls data from that simple table? If you configured your web.config settings correct, then yes, simply dropping in a web logon control will work - and you really don't need to write any code for that logon control to work. But this assumes you have tested, checked, and that you can connect, and use and pull data from that use and pulls data from the tables in that database.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just drop a logon control into that web page. However, BEFORE you do that, create a simple test table in that database. Can you open and pull data from that table?

So, you need to setup two connections in your web.config. One connection is for your general code that pulls data from any table in that database. The other connection is the one you specify for users and authentication. Now in most cases, the two connections (one for logons, users and authentication will be the SAME as the other connection you setup for the general code and application to also pull data from that database.

So, the connections will look like:

For general code and NOT logon stuff:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyCoolApp" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyDataBaseName;UID=MyDataBaseUser;PWD=MySillyPassword;
   APP=WebPortal;WSID=WebPortal" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

So the above is a connection to your "general" database that you use for application data.

Now it not clear if you you did or plan to create the authentication tables (the ones that you created with the wizard) and are going to use the SAME database as your application data, or not.

So, the above will get/give/allow your application code to open data tables based on that connection.

So, now in code, you can get the connection string, and open tables etc. with this:

```
Dim conStr as string
conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyCoolApp").ConnectionString

dim rstTable as new DataTable
dim strSQL as string = "SELECT * from tblHotels"
    
Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL,
                   New SqlConnection(conStr))

    cmdSQL.Connection.Open
    rstTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

End Using
```

So the above is a example of "general" code that you write to open + use the database.

However, for the logon (authentication system), you ALSO need to have a connection string in the web.config connection figuration section. It "can" be the SAME database as your applcation - your choice. So, the database where you run those wizards (scripts) to create the tables?

You need to "tell" the system what connection to use for those tables.

So, in the above connection strings area, you specify the conneciton for the WHOLE logon and sucurity system. That conneciton string can be the same passwords and same as the applicaiton setting above - but is slightly differnt in format.

It will look like this:

```
<add name="FBAConnectionString" connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyCoolDatabase;
UID=SomeUser;PWD=SomePassword;
" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

So the above is the "thing" that connects up your logon control. If you add above, then yes, you can just drop in a logon control.

So, this means that you can use a separate database for the logon system, or often we use the same database as the general code connection.

Now, it not clear what template you used to create your web site, but you need one more section. The section that tells how to use the "roles" (what security group(s)) you have.

And you need to tell the system

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlprovider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MySqlProvider" type="ajaxsetuptest1.MySqlprovider" connectionStringName="FBAConnectionString" 
   enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
   enablePasswordReset="true" 
   minRequiredPasswordLength="3" 
   writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="FBAConnectionString" 
     name="MyRoleProvider" type="ajaxsetuptest1.MyRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

So, all of the above configurations once setup will tell the logon system:

What tables to use for membership (in roles). And these settings as you can see are based on the connection you setup.

And you also need to tell the "whole" system what page should the logon page be. Since often you let users go to the web site - but NOT yet logged in. But if you set everything up correctly, then if a user tries to use any web page that requires security? Then the system will automatic direct users to a logon page (you don't even have to write code for this to occur).

So one more setting should tell the system what kind of secuirty you are going to use ,and what web page users will be directed to for a logon page.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

So your logon page you can create (one is created if you used a web site application template) is Login.aspx. It is in that page you can (and would) drop in your logon control.

Most of the above settings - and even the logon page will be all created for you if you use a template when you create the web project.